# Linux - can you compile AND run a program in one terminal line?

Tags: linux, compilation

For example, a program named program.c

```
g++ program.c -o programName
./programName
```

Is there any way to consolidate these two lines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you could write...

```
g++ program.c -o programName && ./programName
```

Which will only attempt to run your program if compilation succeeded.

For a more general approach, you could write a bash script..

```
#!/bin/sh
g++ $1 -o $2 && ./$2
```

Then you could do (provided it's on your `PATH`, it's executable and it's called `mycompile`)...

```
mycompile program.c programName
```

To make this program available on your `PATH`, you can pop it in your `bin` directory or any directory under `echo $PATH`. If you don't wish to do that, open your `~/.bashrc` file and add its parent directory to your `PATH` with `PATH="$PATH:your/new/dir"` (keep in mind all scripts in that folder will be now reachable).

Ensure it's executable (check with `ls -l mycompile`), if not, you can add that permission with `chmod +x mycompile`.

Comment: Thank you. Interestingly enough, I was going to ask next about something similar to what you referred to regarding the script.

Comment: Although, I am new to linux. What is the process for creating the script and where to save it etc?

Comment: @sherrellbc [this looks like it will be useful](http://askubuntu.com/questions/53210/how-to-add-a-script-to-command-list).

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

```
g++ program.c -o programName && ./programName
```

Notice that the commands will run *sequentially*, that is: one after the other.